# Passing a local storage variable to a url and fetch the output of url in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to know how to pass a localstorage variable to an external url and fetch the output of the url.What I am trying to do is that,currently I am having a website which is set as my chrome extension.When I install the extension initially,it shows a pop up window asking email and password of the user.When the user enters his email and password,it is stored in a local storage,This much works fine in my code.And now what I need is that I have to pass this localstorage variable to a url "… http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/**localStorage variable**/2" and should fetch whatever the url returns.ie,I have to pass the variable like the above format.Please help me

```
     function updateIcon(){

         var urlPrefix = 'http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/';
       var urlSuffix = '/2';

       var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {

       if (req.readyState == 4) {

         if (req.status == 200) {


         var item=req.responseText;


         if(item==1){

        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_logged_in.png"});

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""});   

         }

      else{

       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_not_logged_in.png"});

       chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});

       chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""}); 

       chrome.notifications.create(
      'id1',{
       type: 'basic',
       iconUrl: '/icon_128.png',
       title: 'Calpinemate',
        message: 'Hello calpiner',
       buttons: [{ title: 'Mark',
                        iconUrl: '/tick.jpg'
                  },{ title: 'Ignore',
                        iconUrl: '/cross.jpg'}],
       priority: 0},
       function(id) { myNotificationID = id;}
        );


  chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
  if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
    if (btnIdx === 0) {
        window.open("http://www.calpinemate.com/");
    } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
       notification.close();
    }
    }
   });

 chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function() {
  notification.close();
 });


 }

      } 
   else {

        // Handle the error

        alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);

       }

    }

      });
    var url = urlPrefix + encodeURIComponent(localStorage.username) + urlSuffix;
    req.open("GET", url);

      req.send(null);

     }
```

In this code i am reading a url "http://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php" and whatever it returns i fetch it and store it in a variable.Now what I need is that instead of this url i need the above mentioned url to be read.how can I do this?Please help me

Comment: Are you sure it is stored in `localStorage` and not in `chrome.storage.local` (these two are totaly different) ? Besides, it is not clear what the problem is. Are you trying to send an XHR ?

Comment: YES.It is stored in localStorage.What I need is that whatever is stored in the (localStorage.username),should be passed to the above mentioned url.ie for example if I have stored example.calpineetch.com as my email in localStorage.username,then the url becomes http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/example.calpiineetch.com/2".through this format,i will have to access whatever this url returns.It may a 1 or 0.I don't know how to do this.I thing it is possible through XHR.Please help me.

Comment: The localStorage is per domain (not per extension). Where/How do you store the values in localStorage ? Why can't you just use `localStorage.getItem('<REPLACE_THIS_WITH_THE_KEY>')` ?

Comment: But I need to access the url using this localstorage variable.I hope you didn't understand my problem.Actually I am storing the email entered by the user in a pop up window in local storage variable named localstorage.username.And I have to access the url in the format http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/localStorage.username/2.So that I will get the output of this url.

Comment: I mean localStorage.username may not be same all time.it may change.So accordingly I have to access the url.My only problem is that I don't know the syntax to access the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an AJAX to access the URL. You will create the URL dynamically at runtime (based on the value stored in `localStorage.username`. (More info on **[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest)**.)

```
var urlPrefix = 'http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/';
var urlSuffix = '/2';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert('ERROR !!!');
        } else {
            alert('Response: ' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
});
var url = urlPrefix + encodeURIComponent(localStorage.username) + urlSuffix;
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send(null);
```

Additonally, you need to have permission to access that domain:

```
// In manifest.json:
...
"permissions": [
    ...
    "http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/*/2"
]
```

Comment: i think i have to give permission in manifest.json file.But what is its syntax?Please help me..

Comment: Hi can I ask you one more doubt?Is it possible to show chrome notification with buttons in linux? If you get any information about it,will you please share with me?

Comment: For the time being it is not possible, because of a bug (Marc mentioned it in one of your questions). If it comes to my attention that the bug is fixed, I'll let you know (but it is not very likely yo come to my attention, since I don't use linux for Extension development.)

Comment: And how can I set the size of pop up window in chrome extension/

Comment: It depends on how you open the popup window.

Comment: chrome.windows.create({url : "userinfo.html"}); This is the way I open my pop up window.Please help me

Comment: It is all explained very clearly in the **[documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create)**.

Comment: Hi but when I tried to write in the same syntax just like the link you provided, it is not showing the pop up window itself.I hope some error has occured.Please help ME

Comment: @user1991: It is probably not an error in the documentation, but rather in your code. Post a question about it (mentioning what you have tried and what happened) and people will most probably look into it. (Make sure to include some code, because just saying _"I tried but it didn't work"_ does not help in spotting the problem at all ;))

Comment: Yeah I have posted a question regarding this issue.

Comment: Hi I want the same pattern of the above code in form validation also.As I discussed already ie, in the pop up window when the user enters email and password , as the above it gets stored in localStorage.username Now what I want is that I want to check whether such an email exists.For that there is a url that return the status of whether such an email exists or not.If that url returns 1 it means email exists.OtherWise not.I f it does not exists then I should show an error message in the pop up window screen .The url is         http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/email id/3

Comment: I ahve posted a new question on this issue.Please help me